# Problema con distinct de mongo PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

¿Existe alguna consulta o manera de poder realizar un `distinct` pero que no omita los resultados iguales?

Es algo novata la pregunta pero es que soy nuevo en mongo y me surgio esa duda.
Aqui la consulta que estoy haciendo:

```
$con = new MongoDB\Client("conexion a mi servidor ");
$db = $con->miDB;
$coll = $db->miColeccion;
$productos_de_hoy = $coll->distinct("detalle.producto",['ticket' => $value]);
```

**PD**: Estoy usando mongodb en php

Comment: ¿Por que necesitarias obtener valores duplicados?

Comment: La pregunta está muy confusa... el distinct justamente sirve para que no devuelva valores duplicados... y tu dices que quieres un distict pero que incluya valores duplicados... te puedes explicar mejor que es lo que quieres conseguir?